# Loud bang beneath the house, lights flickered

Tags: electrical, noise, rodent

recently I have been hearing loud bangs in my house since two days ago. The bang seems like it comes from near the main entrance and you can feel the bang or the thud below you. The first time it happened was very bad where it was 5-8 bangs I think and there was a strange smell near the entrance (I think it was a burning smell) and the breaker tripped. Since then it was only one or two bangs and the lights flicker. Also, I have noticed to that we may have a rodent problem as we hear scratching in the walls. We have sealed every opening there may be in the house since we moved in but I'm worried that they may bit the cables or something?

Answer (score 6):

A loud bang combined with a breaker tripping is cause for concern. If the house has a basement, try to follow the line that tripped to see if you can find the damage. If you can live without that particular line (say, it's just for the microwave and not the heating system), turn the breaker off and have it checked out.

If you have an old house and there's a chance of Knob and Tube (K&T) wiring, make sure your fire alarms are working and all of the windows can be opened quickly for emergency egress. I recently fixed a house that used to have knob and tube, caught fire and killed two occupants. I came in to repair the damage. The stuff is really dangerous.

I have not seen mice eat Romex wire, but it's possible. Mice are easy to catch with simple wood traps. Around here I can buy a case of 48 for about $20.

Comment: I once had a cat crawl into my crawl space/root cellar basement through a failed vent grill. The kitty decided that some of the old cloth covered (1950s style) wiring looked like a good snack. We discovered it when my wife couldn't get the washing machine to start. It was the worst and last poor decision the cat made. I replaced the old wiring with modern NM-B. **TL;DR:** I wouldn't put it past a mouse or other critter to chew on wiring for a bit until it was no longer capable of chewing...

Comment: I have seen enough rodent-skinned (copper showing) modern plastic NM/B in renovations that I run all my wiring in EMT, or use MC cable where using a cable.